# Web Start download & save as .jar format?

Tags: java, deployment, jnlp, java-web-start

Is it possible to download the jar(s) deployed via Webstart as jar format? (I need it as .jar files)

I need to be able to run my Application (deployed via jnlp) at OS startup or boot time. If not, any other solution?

Only solution I got so far is to download app's jar(s) directly via HTTP.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Can you use the javaws command at startup (or make a init.d script that calls this).

For e.g.

```
javaws <http resource for jnlp>
```